# Liquibase: how to configure sqlFile tag so it can be executed in a particular schema

Tags: liquibase

There is anyway to configure liquibase to connect to some schema, let's call it A, and execute the sqlFile tag in another schema, let's call it B?

Many tags of liquibase seem to have the property "schemaName", but the sqlFile (or the sql) tag does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just have to use whatever syntax your DBMS supports to either fully qualify the objects or to change the 'active' schema. It does mean that whatever user you are using to connect to the database will need permissions in that other schema.

Comment: At the end, I went for the fully qualify the objects solution... Thanks!